# $H$ is a normal subgroup of $D_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, dihedral-groups

$H = \{e, x^2, y, x^2y \}$.

Is there any elegent way to show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $D_8$. Of course i can use bruteforce, but i don't really want to simplify all 32 multiplications. Even if i discard neutral element $7\cdot 3 = 21$ is still pretty huge amount of multiplications.

Comment: Does thinking about the geometry of those symmetries help? (I might try an answer if I knew just what you meant by $x$ and $y$.)

Comment: @Ethan Bolker I'd guess that $x$ is a rotation and $y$ is a reflexion.

Comment: @EthanBolker I'm not sure, but i think $y$ is a rotation, $x$ is reflection? Does it really matter, which element i will label as rotation?

Comment: @Alejo I actually think it does...or not?

Comment: $D_n$ is generated by $r$ (rotation) and $f$ (reflection), satisfying the relations $r^n = e$, $f^2 = e$, $frf = r^{-1}$. You can write $x$ and $y$, if you like, but it's always better to specify it (though it's easy to guess in this case).

Comment: There is another ambiguity: there are two notations, $D_n$ and $D_{2n}$ for the same thing (symmetries of the $n$-gon) :-)

Comment: @Alejo Yeah, that's it i think!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have already proved that $H$ is a subgroup, proving that $H$ is normal is easy because every subgroup of index $2$ is normal.

Comment: I assume that $D_8$ has order $8$.

Comment: It should not be $D_4$, it's just some people name this thing $D_8$, and other people name it $D_4$.